# AEM FileDataStore missing parameter options

Tags: java, amazon-s3, osgi, aem, crx

I am trying to configure the FileDataStore on my local environment on an AEM 6.5.4 Author instance.
That said contrary to what the [documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp54O.png) indicates :

> **File Data Store**
>
> This is the implementation of FileDataStore present in
> Jackrabbit 2. It provides a way to store the binary data as normal
> files on the file system. It uses the
> org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore PID.
> These configuration options are available:
>
> - repository.home : Path to repository home under which various repository related data is stored. By default, binary files would be
>   stored under crx-quickstart/repository/datastore directory
> - path : Path to the directory under which the files would be stored. If specified then it takes precedence over repository.home value
> - minRecordLength : The minimum size in bytes of a file stored in the data store. Binary content less than this value would be inlined.

I can’t seem to find the repository.home nor the minRecordLength configuration options in my Apache Console local environment (see screenshot).

[image]

I have noticed the configuration popup window displays the following text:

> This form is automatically generated from existing properties because
> no property descriptors are available for this configuration. This may
> be cause by the absence of the OSGi Metatype Service or the absence of
> a MetaType descriptor for this configuration.
> I'm not exactly sure what this mean though or if it is related to the issue at hand.

Some guidance on this particular issue is welcomed as I have never configured an AEM FileDataStore. Thanks.

Comment: Could you give any feedback to the provided answer?

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi console is the wrong place for this anyway. I was even not aware, that this OSGi config exists.

The file data store is configured as a framework property. Therefore put in your sling-home directory (= crx-quickstart for AEM) an install folder, and there an file named `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.cfg`.

Here is a real-world example from me. I use this, that my author and publishers share the same datastore. This saves some disk-space (I need a lot of assets locally).

```
path=C:\\aem64\\filedatastore
```

You have to put these settings, before you install AEM. Otherwise your repository is corrupted. Here is an excerpt of my local install-script, to setup a new instance:

```
  echo "Create directory `pwd`/${AEM_DIR}"
  mkdir ${AEM_DIR}
  cd ${AEM_DIR}/

  echo "Copy license file"
  cp ../install-files/license.properties .

  echo "Unpack AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar"
  java -jar ../install-files/AEM_6.4_Quickstart.jar -unpack

  echo "Copy install folder"
  mkdir crx-quickstart/install
  cp ../install-files/org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.cfg crx-quickstart/install/

  if [ ! -d ../filedatastore ]; then
    echo "create filedatastore"
    mkdir ../filedatastore
  fi
  if [ ! -f ../filedatastore/reference.key ]; then
    echo "init filedatastore with reference.key"
    cp ../install-files/reference.key ../filedatastore/
  fi
fi
```

For more information look here:
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/osgi_config.html#config-sling

PS: The reference.key file is generated automatically. You only need a pre-shared file for binary less replication.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I want to do this with using the vanilla Apache Sling Starter jar. If you have ideas, please let me know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569028/add-new-datastore-during-upgrade