# Add new datastore during upgrade

Tags: sling, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I want to migrate binary content from the segmentstore to a new datastore during an repository update. The current version of my repository is 1.6.1. It is using TarMK segmentstore, and has no datastore. In my experience, having binaries in a file datastore offers a considerable boost in performance. So that’s what I want to do with my upgrade to 1.26.0. But how does one copy binaries to a new datastore?

This command migrates my content to the new repository. The application loads the content properly. But there is no datastore.

```
$ java -jar ~/oak-upgrade-1.26.0.jar --copy-binaries 
    --copy-orphaned-versions=false --copy-versions=false 
    --include-paths=/apps/lsa,/content/lsa,/var/recyclebin/content/lsa 
    ../dev-jun-author/sling/repository sling/repository
```

When I try to copy binaries to a new datastore using this command...

```
  $ java -jar ~/oak-upgrade-1.26.0.jar --copy-binaries 
         --include-paths=/apps/lsa,/content/lsa,/var/recyclebin/content/lsa 
         --datastore=sling/repository/datastore ../dev-jun-author/sling/repository sling/repository
```

It has the following output..

> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.263 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.MigrationOptions -
> copyVersions parameter set to 1969-12-31
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.265 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.MigrationOptions -
> copyOrphanedVersions parameter set to 1969-12-31
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.265 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.MigrationOptions - paths
> to include: [/apps/lsa, /content/lsa, /var/recyclebin/content/lsa]
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.265 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.MigrationOptions - Cache
> size: 256 MB
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.269 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.StoreArguments - Source:
> SEGMENT_TAR[../dev-jun-author/sling/repository]
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.271 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.StoreArguments -
> Destination: SEGMENT_TAR[sling/repository]
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.296 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.FileStore - Creating file store
> FileStoreBuilder{version=1.26.0,
> directory=../dev-jun-author/sling/repository/segmentstore,
> blobStore=null, maxFileSize=256, segmentCacheSize=256,
> stringCacheSize=256, templateCacheSize=64,
> stringDeduplicationCacheSize=15000,
> templateDeduplicationCacheSize=3000,
> nodeDeduplicationCacheSize=1048576, memoryMapping=false,
> offHeapAccess=false, gcOptions=SegmentGCOptions{paused=false,
> estimationDisabled=false, gcSizeDeltaEstimation=1073741824,
> retryCount=5, forceTimeout=60, retainedGenerations=2, gcType=FULL}}
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.428 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.ReadOnlyFileStore - TarMK
> ReadOnly opened: ../dev-jun-author/sling/repository/segmentstore
> (mmap=false)
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.601 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.ReadOnlyFileStore - TarMK
> closed: ../dev-jun-author/sling/repository/segmentstore
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.618 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.DatastoreArguments -
> Blobs embedded in SEGMENT_TAR[../dev-jun-author/sling/repository] will
> be copied to FileDataStore[sling/repository/datastore]
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.619 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.DatastoreArguments -
> Source blob store: DummyBlobStore
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.619 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.FileStore - Creating file store
> FileStoreBuilder{version=1.26.0,
> directory=../dev-jun-author/sling/repository/segmentstore,
> blobStore=null, maxFileSize=256, segmentCacheSize=256,
> stringCacheSize=256, templateCacheSize=64,
> stringDeduplicationCacheSize=15000,
> templateDeduplicationCacheSize=3000,
> nodeDeduplicationCacheSize=1048576, memoryMapping=true,
> offHeapAccess=false, gcOptions=SegmentGCOptions{paused=false,
> estimationDisabled=false, gcSizeDeltaEstimation=1073741824,
> retryCount=5, forceTimeout=60, retainedGenerations=2, gcType=FULL}}
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.632 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.ReadOnlyFileStore - TarMK
> ReadOnly opened: ../dev-jun-author/sling/repository/segmentstore
> (mmap=true)
> 24.08.2020 16:43:12.635 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore$SegmentNodeStoreBuilder
>
> - Creating segment node store SegmentNodeStoreBuilder{blobStore=inline}
>   24.08.2020 16:43:12.644 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.scheduler.LockBasedScheduler -
>   Initializing SegmentNodeStore with the commitFairLock option enabled.
>   24.08.2020 16:43:12.654 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.upgrade.cli.parser.DatastoreArguments -
>   Destination blob store: FileDataStore[sling/repository/datastore]
>   24.08.2020 16:43:12.665 [main] *INFO*  org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.file.FileStore - Creating file store
>   FileStoreBuilder{version=1.26.0,
>   directory=sling/repository/segmentstore, blobStore=DataStore backed
>   BlobStore
>   [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.OakFileDataStore],
>   maxFileSize=256, segmentCacheSize=256, stringCacheSize=256,
>   templateCacheSize=64, stringDeduplicationCacheSize=15000,
>   templateDeduplicationCacheSize=3000,
>   nodeDeduplicationCacheSize=1048576, memoryMapping=true,
>   offHeapAccess=false, gcOptions=SegmentGCOptions{paused=false,
>   estimationDisabled=false, gcSizeDeltaEstimation=1073741824,
>   retryCount=5, forceTimeout=60, retainedGenerations=2, gcType=FULL}}

Sling's error log has this output

> 25.08.2020 10:32:35.030 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1598365955029] GET /content/lsa/assets/Screen%20Shot%202020-04-15%20at%204.06.14%20PM.png HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to read external blob with blobId [d4c06d8a7e0b3381caa5c918d6403319d603dd153e5ce32f663e940af55f0326#815933] without specifying BlobStore
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentBlob.getBlob(SegmentBlob.java:248) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentBlob.getNewStream(SegmentBlob.java:253) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentBlob.getNewStream(SegmentBlob.java:84) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.value.jcr.BinaryImpl.getStream(BinaryImpl.java:59) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.26.0]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.LazyInputStream.getStream(LazyInputStream.java:106) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.20]
> at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.LazyInputStream.read(LazyInputStream.java:65) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.20]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2314) [org.apache.commons.io:2.6.0]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2270) [org.apache.commons.io:2.6.0]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:2291) [org.apache.commons.io:2.6.0]
> at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:2246) [org.apache.commons.io:2.6.0]
> at com.peregrine.rendition.RenditionsServlet$StreamResponse.writeTo(RenditionsServlet.java:191) [com.peregrine-cms.base.core:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
> at com.peregrine.commons.servlets.AbstractBaseServlet.doRequest(AbstractBaseServlet.java:133)
> at com.peregrine.commons.servlets.AbstractBaseServlet.doGet(AbstractBaseServlet.java:82)
> at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:266) [org.apache.sling.api:2.22.0]
> at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:137) [org.apache.sling.api:2.22.0]
> at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:342) [org.apache.sling.api:2.22.0]
> at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:374) [org.apache.sling.api:2.22.0]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:283) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:110) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:250) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:123) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.sling.junit.impl.servlet.TestLogServlet$TestNameLoggingFilter.doFilter(TestLogServlet.java:257) [org.apache.sling.junit.core:1.0.26]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.doFilter(RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.java:67) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.7.2]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97) [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter:1.2.6]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:551) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1610) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1363) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:489) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1580) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1278) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:221) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:500) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:547) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:806) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:938) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.18]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I can see the repository has a datastore with some folders. But images in my Sling app are not working. How can I migrate binaries to a datastore using oak-upgrade or other utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this once a long time ago. Your command to split the repository looks correct. You can check the datastore folder after running the oak-upgrade tool to see if there are files created.

Don't forget to create the needed configuration files to use the file datastore before starting Sling on the new (split) repository location.

Create a `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.config` file in the `install` folder which contains at least this property:

```
path="./repository/datastore"
```

Also create a `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNodeStoreService.config` file in the `install` folder which contains at least this property:

```
customBlobStore=B"true"
```

The minRecordLength used by default by the oak-upgrade tool is 16384 bytes.

See https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/osgi_config.html#config-sling for more details.

I would also suggest not to do a partial content migration when splitting off the binaries. Everything in Sling is content, that includes your OSGi bundles etc as well.

Comment: Thanks! I've marked as correct. For me there were two missing pieces: the custom blobstore flag as you mentioned but an important aspect was also how and when the target repository (i.e. repo w. datastore) was initialized. I posted an example for that setup here...  https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-starter/pull/13#issuecomment-682735735